# Backbone code created in 2014 stopped working and I'm not sure how to update it

Tags: backbone.js

I have been using this piece of code on a site for around 5 years. It has stopped working recently. Meaning, it's not longer reaching the render function. initialize works. getStatus works. But it never reaches render.

I was just giving Backbone.js a shot in 2014, but I never ended up doing anything else with the language. So I'm a complete newb with this, but the code below no longer works. I've been trying to debug it with no luck. Can someone help me understand what's wrong?

It was just a small widget that looked up weather conditions view api.openweathermap.org. I checked to make sure I still had access to the API with my key, and I do. So I'm not sure where the problem is.

There are no errors of any kind in the log to help narrow down.

```
/**
 * Get current weather conditions.
 * http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather
 * http://openweathermap.org/weather-data#current
 * http://openweathermap.org/appid
 *
 *
 */
var City = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url:'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
});

var WeatherView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:'#weather_status_form',
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'getStatus');
    this.model = new City();
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    this.getStatus();
  },
  getStatus: function(){
    this.model.fetch({
      data : {
        q: 'evansville+in',
        units: 'imperial',
        appid: 'xxxxxxxx'
      }
    });
    return false;
  },
  render: function() {
    var weather_temp = Math.round(this.model.get('main').temp);

    $('.weather-widget-temperature').html(weather_temp + '&deg;');

    return this;
  }

});
```

Comment: (Doesn't this make you wish code was commented?) (`api` & `2.5` in the same URL - hm.) Please ask an explicit question.

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"? any errors? what is not working? which part of the code?

Comment: Sorry. This code doesn't appear to ever get to the render function. If I add a console.log in the render function, it never gets there.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, using Backbone.js 1.1.2.

Comment: What is the response from the API? Maybe change isn't triggering?

Comment: Yeah, that's where my backbone ignorance is coming into play. I can manually put in the url and see the result. But I can't figure out how to see the response in my code. I've put a console.log in about 10,000 different places to try. That's why I was thinking some Backbone dev might see this and say - your this.model.fetch() is wrong or something. I'd love to provide more details, but that's all I had.